# Weird topology display bug(?) likely caused by subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, topology

Originally, everything worked fine, but suddenly my blender started displaying the topology as shown in the following image. The vertices are also not changing their color when selected, and they aren't movable. Marked steams have disappeared, the UV map is slightly broken, and blender crashes when I try to center the camera on selected vertices (I'm using the num. entf/, key for that).

The original topology should have looked more like the second image, but smoother. If I disable the subdivision surface modifier, the vertices become movable, and I can center the camera again. The other named weird problems are still there though, and reapplying the subdivision surface modifier wont help either.

I'm also using an armature and collider modifier, but after some testing, including removing them, I'm now certain that the issue lies solely with the subdivision surface modifier.

I suspect that this issue might have been caused by a Blender update because, as mentioned, it just suddenly became like that, even in older saved copies.

Im also new to blender, so I might have overlooked something.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? You have enabled "on cage" for the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. This makes the modifier active in *Edit* mode. Maybe this is causing the problems? Disable the first and second icons right next to the modifier name. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDt4k.png

Comment: Im using version 3.6. And turning off "on cage" actually helped, thanks for the help. Is there a way to make it work again though? Modifying the mesh would be a little harder this way, and im also still wondering how "on cage" is seemingly capable of damaging a UV map. @Blunder